# TextView center vertical and width percentage

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two TextViews on the same line and I want they take half of the parent width each one. Moreover, I want to place them in the vertical middle of the parent layout.

I cannot use RelativeLayout because I need to specify the weight and I cannot use LinearLayout because I need to specify the central vertical property.

So what layout should I use?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="text 1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="text 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinearLayout and still center vertically:

```
LinearLayout.... 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: @minipif's answer is correct, it'll give you your desired output. I just didn't have time to write it all out.